# ADFS 2.0 - Customize Home Realm Discovery Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, customization, wif, adfs2.0

I hate the default looks of the Home Realm Discovery (Claims Provider Selection screen) page when multiple STS are added to the ADFS 2.0 Snapin. Below is the default

[image: http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/files/2012/06/image_9_776B8D4C.png]

Can this be Customized. Such that it redirects to `somepage.aspx` where i can login with username and password. Then it returns the claims correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that ADFS doesn't know where you want to login to.

If you always want to login to the same site, there is a cookie that remembers this and won't ask you next time.

You can also use the "whr" parameter to tell ADFS where to go so it doesn't have to ask.

Yes you can customise the screen - refer [AD FS 2.0 Sign-In Pages Customization Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee895356.aspx).

If you want to force FBA, move the Forms entry in

```
<localAuthenticationTypes>
```

in the web.config to the top.

Comment: Forms Based Authentication.

Comment: a doubt ( after long time), I have StarterSTS as Claims Provider Trust for ADFS 2.0. I have Customized StarterSTS to authenticate against SQL store and AD LDS Store. Instead of Going to the above said page (Home Realm i suppose ), how do i redirect to my StarterSTS Login Page ?

Comment: Use the whr parameter e.g. http://www.idmcrisis.com/post/2011/11/03/ADFS-20-Home-Realm-Discovery-Deluxe.aspx. You know that StarterSTS is pretty much deprecated in favour of IdentityServer?

Comment: is the parameter to be provided from the URL? or is it somewhere in the web.config ? I knew StarterSTS is deprecated but it is still safe to use right? ( from security perspective)

Comment: It's in the URL - there's lots of references on the Internet. Safe? - depends on how you use it e.g. is it Internet facing? is it behind a firewall / proxy? Obviously, it's not being updated as new threats are discovered.

Comment: Yup Internet Facing, Behind Firewall and Proxy. We did some heavy customization for StarterSTS to work with mvc and now see Identity Server is mvc :(